# Is there a way in Chrome console to search for strings in console outputs, even those collapsed?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I don't want to just filter the console outputs, but search for string in it (showing or collapsed) as well. Is it possible?

CTRL+F cannot search inside collapsed outputs. For example, if the output is an `Array[3]`, it's shown as a collapsed tree. Even if you click to expand to show details about the array, you can't search in there.

Answer (score 0):

The **Filter** text box now searches inside of collapsed output. For example, in the screenshot below you can see that the POST error with the expanded output contains a call to `reportError`.

[image: expanded output]

When I put `reportError` in the **Filter** box and collapse the POST error, the only messages that aren't filtered out are the POST errors (meaning that you can assume that the `reportError` text is somewhere within the collapsed message.

[image: filtered messages detects text in collapsed section]