# How to get JSON output in Chrome Dev Tools console?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

is there a way to output a json in a nice way in the console?
I just get "> Object" as the tree root and have to manually navigate through the tree which is annoying.

The best case would be to search for a string within that object. Alternatively expanding everything would be ok as well.

Any ideas?

(Was asked before in [Is there a way in Chrome console to search for strings in console outputs, even those collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033820/is-there-a-way-in-chrome-console-to-search-for-strings-in-console-outputs-even) but not answered)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to auto expand objects in Chrome Dev Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464844/is-there-a-way-to-auto-expand-objects-in-chrome-dev-tools)

Answer (score 59):

Got this from [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/777213/copy-json-from-console-log-in-developer-tool-to-clipboard):

> If the right-click -> copy is not available you could try:
>
> 1 - Right-click the object and select "Store as global variable"
>
> 2 - The console will print the new variable's name, for example:
>
> //temp1
>
> 3 - Type:
>
> copy(temp1)
>
> The object is now available in your clipboard.
>
> Tested in chrome 36

I used this in Chrome 65 and worked great.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks.

Comment: Great one! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

ATM your best option is to use `JSON.stringify` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464844/is-there-a-way-to-auto-expand-objects-in-chrome-dev-tools).

There is an [DevTools Console API for Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_console) that allows to customize console output, but it's still experimental.

Comment: This works, but the output is funky with quotes everywhere. The first solution works better, IMO, giving you a nicely-formatted object.